# Configure Eureka Server and client with custom port and address

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a Eureka Server running on default localhost host and port 8761, so i tried to change this default configuration in this way:

```
server:
  port: 6000
  servlet:
    context-path: /myeureka
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

But in this way i can't access eureka dashboard, just using default configuration:

```
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

In my client same thing occurrs, i can't point to another eureka server different from default (localhost:8761), see my configuration:

```
server:
  port: 7000
  servlet:
    context-path: /client-eureka
spring:
  application:
    name: client-eureka
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    eureka-server-port: 6000
    eureka-server-u-r-l-context: /myeureka
```

Lookin in client log i got the following:

```
2018-09-01 09:19:37.175  INFO 4931 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

No matter what port or host i configure in client, always try to reach the default.

**Important**:
I'm using eureka in this version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server/2.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used the same dependency version as yours and cannot find the config path **server.servlet.contextpath**

Instead, you can use either **server.servlet-path** or **server.context-path**

With each of the server configuration, you need to update your client application.yml file too. Remember that /eureka is the default REST endpoint used to register Eureka client with Eureka server

Case 1: Use **server.servlet-path**

Eureka Server:

```
server:
 port: 7000
 servlet-path: /myeureka

eureka:
 client:
   register-with-eureka: false
   fetch-registry: false
```

Eureka Client:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-cloud-eureka-client
server:
  port: 0
eureka:
 client:
   service-url:
     defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:7000/eureka}
 instance:
     preferIpAddress: true
```

Case 2: Use **server.context-path**

Eureka Server:

```
server:
 port: 7000
 context-path: /myeureka

eureka:
 client:
   register-with-eureka: false
   fetch-registry: false
```

Eureka Client:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: spring-cloud-eureka-client
server:
  port: 0
eureka:
 client:
   service-url:
     defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:7000/myeureka/eureka}
 instance:
     preferIpAddress: true
```

**Updated answer:**
Because **server.servlet-path** and **server.context-path** were deprecated, eureka server will be configured as following:

```
server:
 port: 7000
 servlet:
   context-path: /myeureka

eureka:
 client:
   register-with-eureka: false
   fetch-registry: false
```

Eureka client application.yml will be kept as in Case 2.

Comment: Both cases in "context-path" and "servlet-path" are deprecated. (I'm using spring-boot 2.0.4)

Comment: And my client don't have "defaultZone" property

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas I tried but eureka-server-port and eureka-server-u-r-l-context don't help eureka client to get up-to-date eureka server endpoint. Instead, defaultZone does. Can you tell me why do you need to use those 2 properties and which guide or document are you following? We can then together figure out your problem.

Comment: You are right, i changed the configuration putting "defaultZone" and everything works. thanks

Comment: @thanh is there any option to avoid defaultZone ends with /eureka?